# How can I see what I am writing in Netbeans when I run my code?

Tags: c, input, netbeans, console

I use Netbeans for writing C.
My problem is: I cannot see the output of my code. I mean I can see the result but not the process itself.
For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n;
    printf("please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("your number's square is: %d", (n*n));
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code. Netbeans opens two windows.
one for "build, run" and one for "run". It allows me to write in the "run" window.
but I cannot see the text "please enter a number" or what I am writing. I only see a blank page but when I write a number then hit enter "twice". It shows all outputs in the same window at once. Like this:

```
please enter a number:
your number's square is: 25
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)
```

How can I see what I am writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem. This is a known issue with NetBeans 8.2, but I also see the same problem with NetBeans 11.2.

See these NetBeans Bug Reports:

- [Bug 165437 - Standard output in Output window is not flushed after '\n'](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=165437)
- [Bug 269406 - printf() doesnt output to console until scanf() end](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=269406)

Currently there is no fix for the issue, but there is a simple workaround:

- Select your **C** project in the **Projects** panel.
- Right click and select **Properties** from the context menu.
- Select **Run** from the list of **Categories**.
- Change **Console Type** from *Internal Terminal* to *External Terminal*.
- Change **External Terminal** Type from *Default* to *Command Window*.
  [image: ProjectRunProperties]
- Click **OK**.

When you run your project the console will now open in a separate terminal window outside of NetBeans, and your code will work as expected:

[image: consoleWindow]